# SQLite: Merging dates to range

Tags: sqlite, sorting, date, filtering

I have a more complex table with opening time for every day in a year, person, some additional notes etc. grouped by as needed.

However, I'm stuck with a one query.

| date | opening_time | day_of_week | blahblah irrelevant columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | NULL | 7 | ... |
| 2023-01-02 | 12-16 | 0 | ... |
| 2023-01-03 | 8-16 | 2 | ... |
| 2023-01-04 | 8-16 | 3 | ... |
| 2023-01-05 | 8-16 | 4 | ... |
| 2023-01-06 | 8-16 | 5 | ... |
| 2023-01-07 | 8-16 | 6 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-01-14 | NULL | 6 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

```
... group_concat(distinct case when day_of_week between 1 and 5 then ('' || strftime('%d.%m ', date)) else 'WD' end) as 'operating_days', ...
```

where `day_of_week == 0` is used for selected dates (with special status), just for reference, and 1-7 represents Monday to Sunday.

There current output of the query currently is:

```
Opening hours valid on WD and 2023-01-02, 2023-01-07, 2023-02-11, 2023-02-18, 2023-05-01, ,2023-07-08 ,2023-07-15 ,2023-07-22 ,2023-07-29 ,2023-08-05 , 2023-08-12 ,2023-08-19 ,2023-08-26 ,2023-09-02, 2023–09-30.
```

I would like to merge it into intervals for clarity such as:
„Opening hours are valid on Monday to Friday and on 2023-01-02, 2023-01-07, 2023-02-11, …, on Saturdays between 8th July – 2nd September and 30th September".

(never mind the formatting of dates here, this is just illustrative for the explanation).

It's kind of gaps and islands problem yet I'm missing a way how to determine if the days are consecutive Saturdays and at the same time the the first and last in the interval.

I've managed to group the dates to workdays and others via casting and cases. I am aware that it's kind of gaps and islands problem yet I'm missing a way how to determine if the days are consecutive Saturdays and at the same time the the first and last in the interval.

Thank you very much in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

For opening hours, the common expectation is weekly schedules and it's easy to read. Therefore, the best `group by` value will be `week of year`. Since you're looking for `From` and `To` day of week, it seems that weekdays are always open except Saturday. Sundays is always closed. However, if it's not the case, please feel free to tweak the query for your needs if feasible.

- In SQLite, day of week for Sunday is 0. Thus, a lookup table in CTE.
- Group opening dates by week of year; also get from/to `day of week`.

```sql
with cte_day_of_week as (
select 1 as dow, 'Monday'    as day_of_week union all
select 2 as dow, 'Tuesday'   as day_of_week union all
select 3 as dow, 'Wednesday' as day_of_week union all
select 4 as dow, 'Thursday'  as day_of_week union all
select 5 as dow, 'Friday'    as day_of_week union all
select 6 as dow, 'Saturday'  as day_of_week union all
select 7 as dow, 'Sunday'    as day_of_week),
cte_opening_dates as (
select group_concat(date)  as opening_dates,
       min(day_of_week)    as from_dow,
       max(day_of_week)    as to_dow,
       strftime('%W',date) as week_of_year
  from office_hour
 where opening_time is not null
 group by week_of_year)
select o.opening_dates  as weekly_opening_dates,
       'From ' || fd.day_of_week ||
       ' to '  || td.day_of_week as day_of_week_range
  from cte_opening_dates o
  join cte_day_of_week fd
    on o.from_dow = fd.dow
  join cte_day_of_week td
    on o.to_dow = td.dow
```

Result is a 52-row weekly schedules:

```
weekly_opening_dates                                             |day_of_week_range      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
2023-01-02,2023-01-03,2023-01-04,2023-01-05,2023-01-06,2023-01-07|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-01-09,2023-01-10,2023-01-11,2023-01-12,2023-01-13           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-01-16,2023-01-17,2023-01-18,2023-01-19,2023-01-20           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-01-23,2023-01-24,2023-01-25,2023-01-26,2023-01-27           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-01-30,2023-01-31,2023-02-01,2023-02-02,2023-02-03,2023-02-04|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-02-06,2023-02-07,2023-02-08,2023-02-09,2023-02-10           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-02-13,2023-02-14,2023-02-15,2023-02-16,2023-02-17           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-02-20,2023-02-21,2023-02-22,2023-02-23,2023-02-24           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-02-27,2023-02-28,2023-03-01,2023-03-02,2023-03-03           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-03-06,2023-03-07,2023-03-08,2023-03-09,2023-03-10           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-03-13,2023-03-14,2023-03-15,2023-03-16,2023-03-17,2023-03-18|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-03-20,2023-03-21,2023-03-22,2023-03-23,2023-03-24,2023-03-25|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-03-27,2023-03-28,2023-03-29,2023-03-30,2023-03-31           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-04-03,2023-04-04,2023-04-05,2023-04-06,2023-04-07           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-04-10,2023-04-11,2023-04-12,2023-04-13,2023-04-14           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-04-17,2023-04-18,2023-04-19,2023-04-20,2023-04-21           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-04-24,2023-04-25,2023-04-26,2023-04-27,2023-04-28           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-05-01,2023-05-02,2023-05-03,2023-05-04,2023-05-05           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-05-08,2023-05-09,2023-05-10,2023-05-11,2023-05-12,2023-05-13|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-05-15,2023-05-16,2023-05-17,2023-05-18,2023-05-19           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-05-22,2023-05-23,2023-05-24,2023-05-25,2023-05-26,2023-05-27|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-05-29,2023-05-30,2023-05-31,2023-06-01,2023-06-02           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-06-05,2023-06-06,2023-06-07,2023-06-08,2023-06-09,2023-06-10|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-06-12,2023-06-13,2023-06-14,2023-06-15,2023-06-16           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-06-19,2023-06-20,2023-06-21,2023-06-22,2023-06-23           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-06-26,2023-06-27,2023-06-28,2023-06-29,2023-06-30,2023-07-01|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-07-03,2023-07-04,2023-07-05,2023-07-06,2023-07-07,2023-07-08|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-07-10,2023-07-11,2023-07-12,2023-07-13,2023-07-14           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-07-17,2023-07-18,2023-07-19,2023-07-20,2023-07-21           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-07-24,2023-07-25,2023-07-26,2023-07-27,2023-07-28           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-07-31,2023-08-01,2023-08-02,2023-08-03,2023-08-04           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-08-07,2023-08-08,2023-08-09,2023-08-10,2023-08-11           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-08-14,2023-08-15,2023-08-16,2023-08-17,2023-08-18           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-08-21,2023-08-22,2023-08-23,2023-08-24,2023-08-25           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-08-28,2023-08-29,2023-08-30,2023-08-31,2023-09-01,2023-09-02|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-09-04,2023-09-05,2023-09-06,2023-09-07,2023-09-08           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-09-11,2023-09-12,2023-09-13,2023-09-14,2023-09-15,2023-09-16|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-09-18,2023-09-19,2023-09-20,2023-09-21,2023-09-22           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-09-25,2023-09-26,2023-09-27,2023-09-28,2023-09-29           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-10-02,2023-10-03,2023-10-04,2023-10-05,2023-10-06           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-10-09,2023-10-10,2023-10-11,2023-10-12,2023-10-13,2023-10-14|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-10-16,2023-10-17,2023-10-18,2023-10-19,2023-10-20           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-10-23,2023-10-24,2023-10-25,2023-10-26,2023-10-27,2023-10-28|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-10-30,2023-10-31,2023-11-01,2023-11-02,2023-11-03,2023-11-04|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-11-06,2023-11-07,2023-11-08,2023-11-09,2023-11-10           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-11-13,2023-11-14,2023-11-15,2023-11-16,2023-11-17           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-11-20,2023-11-21,2023-11-22,2023-11-23,2023-11-24,2023-11-25|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-11-27,2023-11-28,2023-11-29,2023-11-30,2023-12-01,2023-12-02|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-12-04,2023-12-05,2023-12-06,2023-12-07,2023-12-08,2023-12-09|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-12-11,2023-12-12,2023-12-13,2023-12-14,2023-12-15,2023-12-16|From Monday to Saturday|
2023-12-18,2023-12-19,2023-12-20,2023-12-21,2023-12-22           |From Monday to Friday  |
2023-12-25,2023-12-26,2023-12-27,2023-12-28,2023-12-29,2023-12-30|From Monday to Saturday|
```